# Apple WatchKit, building an app with the same UI As OS

Tags: ios, user-interface, watchkit, apple-watch

I am new to Watchkit and see that most apps built for it are basic in UI interaction.
Is it possible in iOS 9 and WathcOS2 to build an app that looks like the OS itself? meaning right now in the watch the user looks at the home screen all apps appear like a honeycomb on that screen. Can I build an app on Watch that will load UI to look like the honeycomb apps on the homescreen?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the APIs in either WatchKit 1 or WatchKit 2.